# Create a padded, centered, scaled NSImage

Tags: cocoa, nsimage

I'm putting a fixed size icon based on an arbitrarily sized image into an NSOutlineView using an NSImageCell.

NSImageCell will scale the image down nicely, but I can't find a way to add padding around the scaled image.  The rows look ugly to my eye without padding.

My first pass at fixing this problem was to create a new image of constant size, inset its bounds for padding, then use drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction: to draw a scaled down version of the original icon.

That works great for square images.  I would've guessed there'd be a convenience method on NSImage to draw a centered, scaled-with-constant-aspect-ratio version of the image in a given rect, but I can't find it.

Obviously I can calculate an appropriate rect with the same aspect ratio as the original image, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every sample code I saw use a computation for the padding. There is some <strike>[NSImage categories on CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSImageCategory)</strike> that do that.

Comment: They're gone now. Sadface.

Comment: If any wanted, you can find it in [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20111013161350/http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSImageCategory)